# Refresh div only when external content changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have several div's that fetch separate pages and refreshes the content every x seconds. They are to show live score updates from football matches and currently refresh every 90 seconds when games are being played and 90000 seconds when games are not being played (to effectively turn the refresh off).

The issues I currently have are...

- Before games start, I have to go through the pages and change the javascript timer manually and re-upload the files, doing the same once games are finished.
- Even at 90 seconds, with around 100 people often viewing the site, the server takes a bit of a hammering and can either slow down or just giving a 500 internal server error.
- If I forget to turn it off (or cannot because I have no signal on my phone) after games, when traffic increases as people start getting back home the site really takes a pounding for a few hours - and this caused our site to get locked for a few weeks.

An example of the code in question is

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mdetails").load("/content/phppages/matchdetailsbase.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#mdetails").load('/content/phppages/matchdetailsbase.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 90000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

That one is from http://www.margate-fc.com/content/1st_team/fixtures_results/match_detailsnew.php?all_games_id=4733 and refreshes the entire main content area (under 'Match Details'). There is a similar one on the 'Matches' block at the top of the left column.

match_detailsnew.php contains 5 different queries so suggestions I have read to check for database changes would be hard to implement here.

Admittedly, that code was copy/pasted from somewhere as I knew nothing about JQuery then and though I now very little still it is on my learning curve. The set-up of the whole site is awful but it was my first attempt at a dynamic site around 4 years ago and I am currently rebuilding it from the ground up. With this I will get myself familiar with polling the database for changes and refresh based on that. However, that is a long way off and we desperately need a solution now!!

What I would like, is for jQuery to check if matchdetailsbase.php's output has changed at all (bearing in mind this would be a change anywhere on the page generated by any of the 5 queries) and if it has, to refresh the div, assuming that this will not be putting the same strain/page hits on the server than the constant refreshing does.

If, there would be issues doing it this way because of my set-up, an alternative would be to create a variable for the refresh time that I can change in one place and will be recognised by all of the divs. I tried this by setting $refreshtime = 900 in my config file and then changing the script to

```
 $("#mdetails").load('/content/phppages/matchdetailsbase.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, <?php echo $refreshtime; ?>);
```

This did not seem to make a difference, whatever I put in $refreshtime, but even if it did, I realised that as $refreshtime is outside of the refreshing div, it would not pick up any changes to it so what ever it was set at when the page first loaded would always remain until the full page was manually refreshed, even if I changed it in config.php.

As mentioned before, this is really a short term fix as the site is being rebuilt so I really do not mind a down and dirty hack if need be!

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 3):

After reading the question, if I understand the problem you are facing correctly, the solution is not to be had in the jquery part. The solution can be found in the php part. As you said, the main problem is that the server takes a hammering due to the requests for matchdetailsbase.php. So even if you correctly implement *rcsole*'s solution, your php page would still be hit on each tick of the timer which would in turn run all the code and still cause your servers to get hammered.

The long term solution is of course a combination of query / db changes and some aggressive caching techniques. But since you mentioned that it is a short-term stop-gap solution that you are looking for, I would suggest to go with some good php based output caching. Below are some links to point you in the right direction for output caching.

http://php.dzone.com/news/php-caching-pages-with-output-

[Caching HTML output with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355830/caching-html-output-with-php)

The basic theory is that, you store the output of your php script in a static file and then serve the contents of the file for the next x seconds. So, no matter how many times your php script is called from the client, the content is generated only once every x seconds. This should lower the processing your server has to handle - hopefully. Remember this is just a short-term solution. In your case, i would suggest to keep the caching duration to around 120 - 180 seconds.

This in addition to *rscole*'s solution should help you to hold on until you improve the overall design...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** as @fijas points out my solution would not solve the server hammering issue as you would still be sending requests. The issue should be solved server-side.

From the jquery docs:

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

In theory if the page is the same it should return `304`, right? So what I would do is check if status is `304`, if so pass otherwise refresh.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Edit**: This might be related [Refresh div, but only if there is new content from php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578579/refresh-div-but-only-if-there-is-new-content-from-php-file?rq=1)

**Edit 2**:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#mdetails").load("/content/phppages/matchdetailsbase.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $.get({
      url: "/content/phppages/matchdetailsbase.php",
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        if (textStatus == "notmodified") {
          pass
        } else {
          $('#mdetails').html(data);
        }
      }
    });
   }, 90000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

Does that make sense to you? Might not be correct though. Not sure.

Comment: That bit of code is beyond me but taking a stab at it, "not-here.php", would be my page that is being called? Presumably I could somehow use 'If ( status ==' to compare the current version of that page with the last loaded version and if different, put the refresh bit of code between the innermost curly braces?

Two questions though, what would I use to check the current version against the last loaded version of matchdetailsbase.php's and where would I set the interval to check it?

BTW, the link was something I had already seen but using calls to the database to check for updates.

Comment: I definitely think I understand the logic there. It loads the content initially, checks every 90 seconds to see if the content in matchdetailsbase.php has changed via '(textStatus == "notmodified")'. If that is true it does nothing but if false, will refresh?

I have not got time to implement this yet (as I am actually off to watch the game) but will give it a go this evening. The only bit that confuses me is the textStatus == "notmodified" bit. Is notmodified a term recognised by jQuery or is it just psuedo code and I will have to implement my own criteria there?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: whenever you send an http request you should get an status code. jQuery has `success`, `notmodified` and `error`, if I am not mistaken. Let me know when you try and if it works.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the advice. I had a quick play last night and think that with the amount of work in question, it may be easier to completely rethink the way it is done. Long-term the refresh will be dictated by database changes so, for now, my idea now is to create a separate table called `updates` and each time one of the tables used by the queries is updated, add a new row to `updates` with a timestamp. In my page use jQuery to check if `updates` has a new row since the last refresh and if so refresh the div. Admittedly, without having a read up, I am just guessing this will work!

Comment: Actually that would not solve the problem as I see it. As you would still be performing queries to the database very often. Instead you'd have to just notify your page every time a new row has been added to updates, not the other way around. Hope that makes sense.